# Embedded Coder not recognizing tokens in default code generation template

Tags: matlab, embedded, code-generation, simulink, rtw

I recently obtained a license to use Embedded Coder with an existing Simulink model that we have developed.  In attempting to generate C code for the first time from the model, I am working through several errors.  At first, we had no code generation templates (.cgt) files defined in the model parameters.  After some hunting, I found the default template that comes with MATLAB (*matlabroot*/toolbox/rtw/targets/ecoder/ert_code_template.cgt).

The latest is that I get errors on nearly every token in this default code generation template.

Since I'm just trying to get something to build, at first I commented out the offending lines (things like RTWFileVersion, etc), but now I am noticing that it's giving me errors for things that are mandatory (ie. Types).  Types is one of several required items that must be in the .cgt file, so what's wrong that causes MATLAB to not recognize these tokens?  I'm guessing something may be messed up with my installation, such as a path.

Other details:
Simulink R2013A x32
Target is a Freescale device

Comment: Hi! Have you tried a basic example? Which target configuration file are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Matthias W for getting me to check other configuration options.  Turns out I had selected a .tlc file that was probably incompatible with Embedded Coder.

In Code Generation for "System target file" I have selected the ert.tlc file and now I am able to build the parts of my model I'm interested in.